# How to capture output for current running node

Tags: node.js, adapt

I have the Adapt Author running on a Linux server that I cannot run `node server` against as it restarts itself when I attempt to kill it. Giving me `listen EADDRINUSE :::5000` when I try.

Is there anyway to tap into the current running node's console output so that I can debug an error in the app?

I understand I can get the process PID using `ps aux | grep node`.

Comment: It is a bit of offtopic, but `listen EADDRINUSE :::5000` means that your app cant bind to 5000 port, since it is already taken by some different app. Find which process use this port and kill it. Then run your app.

Comment: Hey @SergeyYarotskiy it's the existing Adapt Author that is restarting itself. I kill it and then it's instantly back in the process list. Not sure if someone has set something to have it do this but it's making it really awkward to actually get it up and running with the console attached.

Comment: Thats what I'm talking about. It is running. You are not fully killing it. It is impossible to process in linux to just restart it self after death. There is something else. Kill everething related. Restart pc...

Comment: Yeah found out ForeverScript was running, calling StopAll on it still wouldn't stop it so replaced the repository and all seems to be working now. Still unsure how I get output from a currently running node server process.